# Is phpunit required in root composer file if other modules require it?

Tags: composer-php, phpunit

Is phpunit required in root composer file if other modules require it?

Some dependencies have phpunit required, does this mean I also need phpunit in my root composer file for these dependencies to completely work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No, usually you only need to add the dependencies you want to use. Whatever these dependencies need, they should define themselves.

For example your project requires library A & C. If library A says it requires library B then composer will also download that and you don't have to care about it. When library B defines library C & D as dependency it will download library D as well and check if both you and library B require a version of library C that can be used or throw an error, that either you or library B need to change the version requirements for library C.

If library A and B have phpunit in their dev-dependencies, then composer will ignore those, because `require-dev` signifies that this dependency is not needed to use the library, only for development. Composer will only download your dev-dependencies (unless you use `--no-dev`, e.g. on your prod server where you also don't need development dependencies, because you only want to run your project).

**You should only define dependencies that you use directly as root dependencies (all of them, even if your dependencies already provide them).** Those dependencies, that you use, define themselves what they need and composer will resolve all those requirements for you and determine what to download and which version.

If you see a library that you don't know why it's there, you can also use `composer why <vendor/library-name>` to find out why it was installed.